# Deriving Snell's Law from Fermat's Principle, why do we differentiate only with respect to $x$?

Tags: optics, refraction, variational-principle, variational-calculus

I'm confused about why we only differentiate with respect to the X when deriving Snell's law. Can someone explain why we do not also do a differentiation with respect to Y.

For more clarification about the question please see the following screenshots:

[image: simple diagram of ray entering a different medium]

[image]

My question is why do they only do dt/dx and not dt/dy?

Comment: The answer is given by Floris. By the way take a look in my answer therein : [Why one should follow Snell's law for shortest time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257140/why-one-should-follow-snells-law-for-shortest-time/257331#257331). May be useful.

Comment: I am confused by this question. I see no y in either the diagram or the equations.

Comment: ^by 'y' I was referring to the general Y axis direction.

Answer (score 0):

The value of y is constant in your diagram - namely the front face of the glass. If you had a curved surface you would integrate with respect to both x and y - but here y is constant and the derivative is trivially zero.