# Derivation of relationship between speed of light in two mediums and the angle of refraction and incidence

Tags: visible-light, refraction

I came across the following equation for the speed of light in different medium and the angle of reflection(Θ<sub>1</sub>) and refraction(Θ<sub>2</sub>):

> sin(Θ<sub>1</sub>)/sin(Θ<sub>2</sub>)=v<sub>1</sub>/v<sub>2</sub>=constant

My textbook does not give any derivation of this relationship, but uses it to derive Snell's law. I was hoping someone could provide a derivation of this relationship, as I could not find it elsewhere.

Comment: [Why one should follow Snell's law for shortest time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257140/why-one-should-follow-snells-law-for-shortest-time/257331#257331).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.animations.physics.unsw.edu.au/jw/light/Snells_law_and_refraction.htm

This link might help you find your answer

Comment: Sini/sinr is supposed to be Snell's law

Comment: Hope you understood and got the answer to your question

Comment: It will be better if you copy important parts of the web page, so that the content is not lost in case of a link rot.