# Proof of Snell's law

Tags: optics, refraction, geometric-optics

Snell's law states that $n_1 \sin i = n_2 \sin r$ where $i$ is the angle of incidence, $r$ is the angle of incidence and the refractive index, $n = \frac{c}{v}$ where $v$ is the velocity of the light ray in the given medium.

I wonder how the $\sin$ comes into play and how one would derive it as I was only taught the formula and not the derivation in school. I welcome multiple proofs because I really want to understand *why* Snell's law works from multiple angles.

Comment: Duplicate [Why Does Snell's Law use Sine Instead of Angle Values?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/334145/) and [Snell's law and Fermat's principle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/493365/) amongst others.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Does Snell's Law use Sine Instead of Angle Values?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/334145/)