# About an angle approximation used in Feynman's treatment of Fermat's principle

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, geometry

In [this](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_26.html) lecture about Fermat's principle, Feynman derives the refraction law using the principle of least action. He finds the shortest path between $A$ and $B$ by defining a variable point $X$ and setting its distance to the point corresponding to the shortest path, $C$, to zero. He said,

> If we were to plot the time it takes against the position of point X, we would get a curve something like that shown below, where point C corresponds to the shortest of all possible times. This means that if we move the point X to points near C, in the first approximation there is essentially no change in time. 
>   [image]

In deriving Snell's law, he used the following approximation:
$$ \angle XCF\approx \angle BCN'    ~~~(\text{when $X$ is near $C$}),$$

[image]

Where did this approximation exactly come from?

Comment: Related : [Why one should follow Snell's law for shortest time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257140/why-one-should-follow-snells-law-for-shortest-time/257331#257331).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the lines BC and BF were parallel, this would be exact.

Is X is close to C, I.e. F is close to C, those lines are close to parallel and the approximation is good.  What is “close”? Much closer than B is far away, so the lines become parallel. That’s a bit circular, but this proof relies on infinitesimals: “if it’s not a good enough approximation, pick a closer point and repeat until done”