# Law of refraction

Tags: optics, waves, visible-light, refraction, geometric-optics

In my textbook it is given that "The refractive index of a substance **does not depend on the angle of incidence"**

But

```
Refreactive index =sine of angle of incidence/sine of angle of refraction
```

It is clear from above relation that refractive index depends on angle of incidence.Where am I wrong?

Comment: Related : [Why one should follow Snell's law for shortest time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257140/why-one-should-follow-snells-law-for-shortest-time/257331#257331).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the equation and the statement are right. You just misunderstood the meaning. Actually, the refractive index of a medium does not depend on the angle of incidence. It remains constant. That is, when the angle of incidence changes the angle of refraction also changes and adjusts. Thus the refractive index remains same whatever the angle of incidence be.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is great. Just wanted to distill it down to the most basic statements that could be made.

**Refractive index** is a property of a **material**.

**Angle of incident** is a property of a light **ray**.

Answer (score 0):

The angle the incident ray made with normal and the angle made by refracted ray with normal are changed, but ratio of two is remained constant! The ratio is the refractive index.