# Fermat's principle solving for angle of incidence

Tags: refraction

Snell's law can be derived from [Fermat's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell%27s_law), which states that the light travels the path which takes the least time. It finds the path by setting dT/dx=0 to arrive at n_1 sin θ_1= n_2 sin θ_2. Since there is this one equation with two variables: θ_1 and θ_2, solutions are infinite where  θ_2=〖sin〗^(-1) (n1/n2)sinθ_1.
Assuming there are three light waves travel from air n_1 = 1 to glass n_2 = 1.5 between two fixed endpoints (a_1, b_2)  and (a_1, b_2) with the following (θ_1, θ_2) solution pairs: (30°, 19.5°), (45°, 28.1°), (60°, 35.3°) as shown below.

[image: Three waves W1, W2 and W3 travels from medium 1 to medium 2 in least time.]

Only W2 can end at point (a_1,b_2)? I know that this would work if we don't fix the endpoints and make W1 and W3 pass through W2's incident point. But just wonder how to interpret the least time path derivation.

[Edited] Thanks for showing me the [link](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/Fermat.html). From there, I was able to figure out my mistake. The Snell's law states the refraction angle relationship to medium indices at the incident point x. Fermat's Principle proves it by finding the minimum of total travel time T(x) by setting dT/dx = 0 where x can be expressed in terms of the begin and end points (a1, b1) and (a2, b2) as:
(x - a1)/sqrt[(x - a1)^2 + b1^2] = (a2 - x)/sqrt[(a2 - x)^2 + b2^2] (n2/n1)
which reduces to Snell's law.
So we can solve x in terms of the positional values and it is UNIQUE.
That's why in my graph, only W2 hits the target (a2, b2), not any other waves. Solving x from the above equation is numerically harder than Snell's law. The former is asking, given the begin and end points and without knowing θ1 or θ2, what is x, and the latter is asking, given an incident angle θ1, what is θ2.

Comment: 1. Those aren't 3 waves. They are 3 rays, as understood in geometrical optics (which would come from 1 spherical wave in this case). 2. I'm not sure I understand your question. Snell's Law relates the difraction angle for some incident angle. The difracted rays do not generally have a common focus but the point at which two of them intersect is always before or after the incident ray focus, depending on whether $n_{1} < n_{2}$ or viceversa, respectively.

Comment: See the reference [Section: Fermat's Principle and Refraction](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/Fermat.html) where the derivative of the time to travel the path versus the path is set to zero to derive Snell's Law from Fermat's principle.  Please let me know if this is helpful.  Also [this general search using keyboards "Derivation of Snell's Law using Fermat's Principle"](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu-sn&q=Derivation+of+Snell%27s+Law+using+Fermat%27s+Principle) has videos and so forth in case something simpler than the first reference is required.

Comment: @Leon Chang - I am glad to help!  I am also glad that you enjoined the link [http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/Fermat.html](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/Fermat.html) and appreciate your feedback!  I appreciate that an imperfect question is hard to answer; there is a lot of work to represent the question in a format that it can be perfectly answered.  Plus, there is no sense to re-ask the question in the answer since an online reference has the worked-out question and answer.  Even so, I upvoted your question - for me it is obvious what you are looking for.

Comment: Related : [Why one should follow Snell's law for shortest time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257140/why-one-should-follow-snells-law-for-shortest-time).

Comment: This link has a scenario of finding the optimal path of a lifeguard running and swimming to rescue a swimmer. It is basically asking: given the begin and end points, where the incident point x is. This requires an [iteration program](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FuyA6zlh8uIGeVqMnRZqow00HnybwrjG/view) to find x which is harder than knowing an endpoint and an incident angle.