# When light passes from one medium to another. Depending on the density, it would experience a change in velocity. Why would its vector change as well?

Tags: optics, visible-light, speed-of-light, refraction, wave-particle-duality

For example, when light passes through water its velocity decreases and refraction occurs. Why? Why is there a change in direction. If I slow down a car I don’t suddenly turn left.

Comment: a car is not a wave but light is

Comment: Obligatory 3B1B: https://youtu.be/Cz4Q4QOuoo8?t=36

Comment: @hyportnex by quantum, a car technically also is a wave... lol

Comment: @naturallyincosistent you are right but its wavelength is soooooooooooooooooooo shooooooooooooooort................

Comment: You do turn if one side hits the dirt before the other side. Light only changes direction when it hits at an angle.

Comment: Textbk answer is Fermat's principle

Comment: Related : [Why one should follow Snell's law for shortest time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257140/why-one-should-follow-snells-law-for-shortest-time).

Comment: @user6760 Fermat's principle or its equivalent Snell's law of refraction is not an explanation, it is an axiom of geometric optics or can be taken as a consequence of short wave *asymptotics* of wave propagation. I think *ANewLearner* is asking for an explanation that a 12yo child can understand, not an easy task.

Answer (score 0):

> For example, when light passes through water its velocity decreases and refraction occurs. Why? Why is there a change in direction. If I slow down a car I don’t suddenly turn left.

Imagine your car is sliding down an icy hill at a 45° angle, just ahead the ice ends at a 0° angle. One side will hit the pavement before the other. The side that hits first will slow down and the car will pivot while the end on ice continues at its original speed. When the car is fully on the pavement it will have refracted to a new angle. The slower medium is the pavement with a higher coefficient of friction than the ice.

Since most people drive their cars in a 90° angle (and not 45°), there is no rotation since the motion is perpendicular to ice/pavement interface.

A wavefront ( light, sound) approaching at a 45° will undergo the same pivot as one end slows down while the other end remains at the same speed until the wavefront is completely in the slower medium. For light the slower medium has a higher index of refraction.

Comment: how does this answer explain why light refracts in a dielectric medium?

Comment: @hyportnex Thanks for the feedback. I've updated my answer.