# The principle of least action

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action

I have read about the [principle of least action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action). This principle suggests that nature would allow a particle to travel in a path along which the integral of the difference between kinetic energy and potential energy is minimum.

1. Is this a basic law of nature?
2. Is it completely independent of other basic laws of nature like conservation of energy and conservation of angular momentum?
3. At the same time I would like to know how was it reached at, cause this doesn't seem to be something that we can easily identify and generalize.

Comment: You should read about Noethers Theorem! Its closely related to the Lagrangian Mechanics and Conservation Laws!

Comment: @HritikNarayan : What should we assume while carrying out a formulation using this law . Should we consider that law of conservation of energy can be derived from this law ?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [Why the principle of least action?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15899/50583)

Comment: Subquestion 3 is essentially a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78138/2451