# Is there any reason for principle of least action to be true?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action

My question is not rigidly related to physics. The principle of least actions says that for any dynamical system there exists a function parameterized by $q$'s and $\dot{q}$'s such that the line integral of the function from state $A$ to state $B$ with respect to the parameter $s$ is stationary. Is there any rigorous mathematical proof of the principle?

Can I apply the principle of least action to study the evolution of a dynamical system in phase Space?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I show that there exists variational/action principle for a given classical system?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20298/)

Comment: The question [Why the Principle of Least Action?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15899/) is also related.