# Proof of Hamilton's principle

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, action, variational-calculus

Is there a anything like a proof of Hamilton's principle? Where would I find it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why the Principle of Least Action?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15899/)