# Why does nature favour systems that follow from a variational principle?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, variational-principle, action

When Newton discovered ‘Newton’s law’ he was probably not aware that it could be viewed as a consequence of minimizing an ‘action integral’ (integral of some Lagrangian density).

Since the same is true in quantum physics as well, I am wondering why variation principles (VP) play such a pivotal role in physics.
Why does nature seem to favour systems whose dynamics follow from a VP of some kind?

Are there dynamic systems that cannot be derived via a VP? If yes, what is a simple example?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15899/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20298/2451 and links therein.