# In what situations would it be more beneficial to use Newtonian Formalism vs Lagrangian Formalism?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

I'm studying for an exam in Classical Mechanics, and I was curious to know when it is more appropriate to use Lagrangian vs Newtonian Formalism. I know that Lagrangian Formalism much more efficient, however in another physics class I was in, we hardly used Lagrangian formalism at all, and primarily used newtonian.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8903/2451 and links therein.